# simple numerology with javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

Hey everyone i'm a newbie so please be nice. I've done a search and found stuff related to python but none to JS.

I'm half way through my code academy course on JS and am trying to apply what I've learnt so far in creating a simple numerology script. So far i've learnt functions, loops, variables, and array positions so i imagined this task should be achievable.

The aim is for the user to input their name and the script automatically calculate the value of it according to numerology rules.

For example:

A:1, J:1, S:1, B:2, K:2, T:2, C:3, L:3, U:3, D:4, M:4, V:4, E:5, N:5, W:5, F:6, O:6, X:6, G:7, P:7, Y:7, H:8, Q:8, Z:8, I:9, R:9

So the name TOM would equal 12 because of (2+6+4).

I haven't gotten very far regarding creating a working script and don't really know how to proceed. So far I'm able to isolate the first character in the name but I don't know how to convert it to a number, or how to do the same with the remaining characters:

```
var x = {A:1, J:1, S:1, B:2, K:2, T:2, C:3, L:3, U:3, D:4, 
M:4, V:4, E:5, N:5, W:5, F:6, O:6, X:6, G:7, P:7, Y:7, H:8, 
Q:8, Z:8, I:9, R:9};

name = prompt ("Type your name in CAPS"); //for example: TOM
name = name[0]; // first letter is T
console.log(name[0]); // prints T
console.log(x.T) // prints 2


console.log(x.(name[0])); //not working. I thought it would also print 2??
```

Comment: Try using `x[name[0]]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Please try following code. Here's explanation of what I have done:

1. First you need to assign the inputted name in a variable ( [You should always use `var` keyword while declaring new variables unless you intentionally want to make it global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it) )
2. Once you have the name, you need to loop through each character in the name. You can use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) for this, and [`length` property of `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) as the loop limiting condition.
3. Now, in each iteration of the `for` loop, you get one character of the name string. You can use this character to get the value for the matching key, using `x[ currentCharacter ]` e.g. x["T"].
4. You need to keep a counter variable to store the sum of all character values, so I have declared the `nameScore` variable before the loop and assigned it an initial value of `0`. Each iteration gets the corresponding value for the current character and adds the numeric value to `nameScore`. By the time the loop finishes, `nameScore` contains the sum of all character values in the name string. You can `console.log()` or `alert()` it, or use in any other way you want.

**Second part: Getting single digit value of the nameScore**
For this part, I followed following steps ( there may be other approaches possible ):

5. First condition we need to check is that `nameScore` is greater than 10, otherwise it's already single digit. This check also helps if we the sum of digits is again more than a single digit and we need to calculate the single digit sum again. I have used `while` loop for this.
6. In the while loop, we need to again keep a counter( initialised at 0 ), iterate through each digit and add it to the counter. To loop through it, we first convert it to a `string` ( using `''+singleDigitScore`) so that we can access `length` property and use `charAt()` to get individual digits. As `charAt()` returns a string representation of the digit, we use `parseInt()` to convert it to number before adding it to our counter. If the resulting number is less than 10, the loop is exited, otherwise the same loop runs again with number updated to the new number just calculated.

   ```js
   var x = {A:1, J:1, S:1, B:2, K:2, T:2, C:3, L:3, U:3, D:4, 
       M:4, V:4, E:5, N:5, W:5, F:6, O:6, X:6, G:7, P:7, Y:7, H:8, 
       Q:8, Z:8, I:9, R:9};
       
       var name = prompt ("Type your name in CAPS"); //for example: TOM
       var nameScore = 0;
       
       for( var i = 0; i < name.length; i++ )
       {
        var curChar = name.charAt( i );
        var curValue = x[ curChar ];
        nameScore = nameScore + curValue;
       }//for()
       
       
       console.log( "Total score for this name is: " + nameScore );

   var singleDigitScore = nameScore;
   while( singleDigitScore >= 10 )
     {
       var total = 0;
       var str = '' + singleDigitScore;
       for( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ )
         {
           total = total + parseInt( str.charAt(i) );
         }//for()
       singleDigitScore = total;
     }//while

   console.log("Single Digit score is: "+singleDigitScore);
   ```

Comment: I'm sure this works, but instead of just dumping the right answer, could you explain briefly what the code does?

Comment: @Juhana Yeah, I'm editing it to add some explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response! and yes an explanation would be much appreciated

Comment: @user6528657 Did it work for you? If yes, please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: yes it worked! quick question. why is when trying to do console.log(nameScore.length) it prints undefined?

Comment: @user6528657 It's because `nameScore` is a `Number` and Numbers do not have a `length` property. What do you expect it to print anyway?

Comment: the next improvement to this script would be to add the digits together if the result is a double digit. so for instance if the nameScore = 23. I need it to then add 2+3 together to = 5.

Comment: i'm trying nameScore.split but it's not working. the intention was to split the result then use a loop as before to add the values to a new variable called nameScore2.

Comment: @user6528657 ok. And if the number is 3 digits, then you want to add the digits until the result is only 1 digit?

Comment: precisely- though unlikely unless you have an extremely long name

Comment: @user6528657 should be taken into account nevertheless. Trying to write some logic for it.

Comment: @user6528657 Please check the updated code.

Comment: great work ! you're genius. If you have the time could you explain what parseInt is doing in this ?

Comment: @user6528657 `parseInt()` converts a string representation of a numeral to a number, so that it can be used in arithmetic operations. I am adding some more explanation in my answer above. Hope that would help.

Answer (score 1):

Totally appreciate the answer by Mohit Bhardwaj, and the explaination behind it also for the questioner who want to learn the basic understanding of JavaScript. so once you are good in that and you know how to iterate through a string, then to learn other javascript utilities and concepts you can still try it in different ways. like slit it to learn how split works and the run map or reduce in array, and then use forEach to learn it, here I am giving a quick example to solve this so you can learn other codes in JavaScript too

```
var name = ..... // first get value in name variable however you want
var sum = name.split('').reduce(function(total, eachNumKey){
return (isNaN(total) ? x[total] : total) + x[eachNumKey]
});
```

Here I am splitting the string into a array, so that I am running a forEach instead of maintain index and fetch by index, then running reduce to calculate sum, (could have map the array first to transform equivalent value array then easily you can sum too, but then will be i iteration of 2 times, but you should learn map also in some other cases).
In reduce for the first time it the first arg is the first value of array, and second is the second , but next time onward first argument will be whatever you returned, and second argument will be the iterator, so just checked with a condition, and mapped to corresponding value need to add. 
Note: Performance wise this is nit the better solution for this particular problem, but if you try every thing with different approaches then you will get to know their uses and when to try what.

Comment: Thanks @Koushik Chatterjee :)